# Can I change the user name for Word 2013 track changes while signed in to an Office account?

Tags: microsoft-word, user

I've been provided a hard copy of comments and changes to a document. My task is to add them to the electronic file. I changed the user name via Track Changes Options (pictured) to the original commenter's name.

[image: Track Changes Options]

This should have enabled me to enter the changes under that name, but I think Word is pulling the name from my Office account. (Shown in the upper right corner of my window, just under the min/max/close buttons.) I can't log out of Office, I can only add another Office account; I imagine this is part of our network security.

Since the tool provided by Word to change my User Name doesn't actually change the user name for the purposes of tracking changes, how *do* I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just click on ***Change User Name*** then under your given User name & Initials check mark the option ***Always use these values regardless sign

Comment: I wish I'd included *one more* screenshot in the original question; I'm certain that check box wasn't in the version of Office provided to me at the time. Regardless, it's there now and does what I needed, so I've checked this as the correct answer.